# REST API + Webserver on embedded SoC running Linux

Tags: c++, rest, embedded-linux, cpprest-sdk

I'm developing an embedded platform and need to provide mechanisms to control and maintain the platform (file upload/download/delete and triggering various actions).

I need to be able to use those functions from a program running on a host machine and also via a simple website hosted on the platform itself.

I've never done this before and am wondering the best way to proceed, so looking for guidance as to what framework and system structure to use.

The platform is running Linux and all other services running on it are written in C/C++, so sticking to C++ seems like a good idea as it simplifies maintenance (no need to learn a new language, anyone in the team can use C++).

I do not want to consume too much CPU/RAM running frameworks, so a compiled language seems appropriate. I do not want to run Java for example.

I'm thinking to use lighttpd to host the website and Microsoft's [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk) to implement the microservice in C++.

The benefit of cpprestsdk is that it's a C++ framework, implementing an HTTP server and with support for JSON. So it looks fairly straight-forward to use it to implement the micro-service.

The drawback of using lighttpd and cpprestsdk is that I have two HTTP servers running on the machine, which seems like a waste of resources.

Would I be better off using CGI with lighttpd to implement my micro-service?